# private static final Date myDate =?

Tags: android

I was having difficult to put correct types for:

```
private static final Date myDate =
```

I tried to put "mm-dd-yyyy" but it said it cannot be a string.
I tried 'mm-dd-yyyy' but it said too many characters in character literal.

I dont know what is other types I should put. Help please.

Comment: you are initializing a field of type `Date` and you try to set it to `"mm-dd-yyyy"` which is obviously a `string`. What are you exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish to have the correct type.  For example: I have private static final String name = "name";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a Date with a specific time you can use a Calendar object.

If you want to have todays Date you can just use:

```
private static final Date myDate = new Date();
```

Specific date:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Date myDate = cal.getTime();
```

That would be 01.01.2015

Comment: With your above code i am getting date like - `Thu Jan 01 22:15:44 GMT+05:30 2015` . how can i get it 01.01.2015 ??

Comment: @TunerSkyline are you getting same output ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
Date date = f.parse(yourString);
```

I expect it will works for you!

**EDIT:** It gives to you an error because you are trying set to your variable `myDate` a `String`, and it's a type of `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...as you can see here:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/